# django test : Getting operational error when running manage.py test

Tags: python, django, testing

I am currently working on testing a simple logic on my django application.

But when i executed the test case, there were operational errors thrown. So i deleted all my test cases and ran the manage.py test, but i still get an operational error.

Can someone please tell me what i am missing while running the django tests?

The error i got is as follows:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\sankar\workspace\alaTest_ProgrammingTest\src\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 322, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 363, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 413, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\test\runner.py", line 151, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\test\runner.py", line 113, in setup_databases
    return setup_databases(self.verbosity, self.interactive, self.keepdb, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\test\runner.py", line 304, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST_SERIALIZE", True),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\creation.py", line 391, in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\creation.py", line 433, in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\core\serializers\__init__.py", line 128, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 52, in serialize
    for obj in queryset:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\creation.py", line 429, in get_objects
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\query.py", line 287, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 699, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 785, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\db\utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 489, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Operators_operator_details
Finished "D:\Users\sankar\workspace\alaTest_ProgrammingTest\src\manage.py test" execution.

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #added the Operators application to the project
    'Operators',
)
```

my installed apps in the settings file are as follows:

Comment: Please show your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: added it to the question. I am using eclipse. And i have the option to run the manage.py test from the console.

Comment: Does changing `Operators` to `operators` help?

Comment: Operators is the name of the module application. It does not work, if i remove it

Comment: Try running `manage.py syncdb` and syncing "Operators".  It's saying that a table is missing.

Comment: Have you deleted the "*.pyc" compiled files? Since you are using Eclipse you cannot see them inside the IDE.